# SQLAlchemy Ambiguous Foreign Key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two classes, `User` and `Address`. A user can have many addresses and one default address. I tried this SQLAlchemy code.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    default_address_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('addresses.id'))
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    nickname = Column(String)

    addresses = relationship("Address", order_by="Address.id", back_populates="user")


class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email_address = Column(String, nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))

    user = relationship("User", back_populates="addresses")


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

It results in the error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.addresses - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

I tried adding `foreign_keys` to the relationship, but I couldn't get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct way, you should remove the foreign key from the default_adderess_id of the user table. if you want to make a difference between default address and other address you can have one more field in address table as type